# Searching a single site with the Microsoft Graph API KQL query

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a few hundred sharepoint sites. I want to search only a few of them for files of extension 'fmp12'. After a lot of trial and error I found a KQL query that searchs for such files:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "FileType:fmp12"
            },
            "region": "EMEA"
        }
    ]
}
```

(I need the region since I'm using an application account)

When I run this query I get matches from all sites. How can I change the query so that it returns items only from those specific sites, or from one site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reduce searching to one specific site, it can be achieved by adding `site` keyword to the `queryString`

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "FileType:fmp12 AND site:\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}\""
            },
            "region": "EMEA"
        }
    ]
}
```

For more sites, use OR

```
"queryString": "FileType:fmp12 AND (site:\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/{site1_name}\" OR site:\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/{site2_name}\")"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter on **Path** within the `queryTemplate` property with the beginning of the URL of your SharePoint site. It could be also useful if you have to search accros multiple sub-sites.

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "FileType:fmp12",
                "queryTemplate": "Path:https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site"
            },
            "region": "EMEA"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can test the API with the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), there are a lot of working samples.